# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a function queue which takes an array (arr) and a number (item) as arguments. Then I add the number to the end of the array, and remove the first element of array. The function should then return the element that was removed.

```
function queue(arr, item) {

arr.push(item);
var removedItem = arr.shift();

return removedItem;  
}
```

Then i get this error: 
RangeError: maximum call stack size exceeded.

Can anyone explain me what is going wrong? In my eyes (beginner), the code looks okay? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the function `queue` called infinitely? maybe inside a l0000000p

Comment: add the code of where you call it

Comment: There is no reason for such error in the provided code. Should be in another place. :)

Comment: Thanks all! It is a challenge in Free Code Camp, but with a 'bug' I guess. 
When i refreshed the page, the function worked..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the page just needed a refresh (see self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is a challenge in Free Code Camp.

The solution in my answer is right. I refreshed the page and it worked.